# How does one unpack a tar file in Android?

Tags: android, tar

I'm not overly familiar with tar, so, this may be a stupid question, but I have a situation where I want to grab a tarball from the server (preferably compressed, but that's not essential), download it on to the device and untar it.

I'm not seeing any standard library to do this... am I overlooking it, or does it not exist?

[EDIT] I'm attempting to do this in my app by means of some API or library that handles unpacking tars - I'm not looking for an app that un-tars stuff on my device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is support for it built into the OS. But you should be able to use a third party library to do it.

[Here is one](http://code.google.com/p/jtar/), I am sure there are others to choose from out there as well.

Comment: The link is broken as of 2018-01-14

Comment: The link is no longer broken as of 2021-0101

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for reviving an old question.

As of 6.0/Marshmallow, Android includes [Toybox](http://landley.net/toybox/about.html), an executable that contains small versions of every utility.

So on 6+ versions of Android, you can execute `tar` command as you would on a normal linux system.

As of Q1 2019, 6.0 and higher represent approximately 90% of Android users, so this is more or less safe to do unless you want full support, or are targeting a market with different Android adoption rates.

Comment: I probably should edit the question to reflect the fact that I'm attempting to do this programmatically in MY app (not as a user of another app). I thought that this would be implicit by virtue of the fact that SO deals with questions about programming and not device/app useage but I can see how this may still be a needed qualifier to avoid wasting people's time. (sorry to have wasted yours and thanks for the advice!) - Genia

Comment: @YevgenySimkin don't be obnoxious. `tar` is perfectly usable inside an app. In fact, there are some apps that use toybox tools other than using up to date libraries like Apache Commons Compress which greatly increases your app size.

Answer (score 2):

Noting down another option here,

Library Name : [Apache Commons Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) Apache License, Version 2.0

The Apache Commons Compress library defines an API for working with ar, cpio, Unix dump, **tar**, zip, gzip, XZ, Pack200, bzip2, 7z, arj, lzma, snappy, DEFLATE, lz4, Brotli, Zstandard, DEFLATE64 and Z files.

Example here:
[Java TAR example – compress and decompress *.tar or *.tar.gz files](https://memorynotfound.com/java-tar-example-compress-decompress-tar-tar-gz-files/)
This demonstrates how to compress files or directories recursively in .tar or .tar.gz format and how to decompress a .tar or .tar.gz file